# Move row to different sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My fellow teachers and I like to send students little google drawings to let them know they've been doing well lately. We have a spreadsheet that we use and I am trying to automate the process of sending them an email when their drawing is ready to be viewed. I started to learn to code and Google Script last week so I lack the skills to troubleshoot any more than the googling I've done already, which turns up scripts that run `onEdit`, and I want to be running the script manually instead. Basically I am trying to write a script that when I trigger it will:

1. Send an email using info put into the spreadsheet
2. Move that row of info from the "Unsent" sheet to the "Sent" sheet
3. Delete the row from the "Sent" sheet

So far I have been able to accomplish steps 1 and 3, but I could use a little help getting step 2. I am trying to use `moveRows()` but I am not sure how to proceed from what I have already tried. Here is what I have so far:

````
  sendPositiveRecognitionEmails();
  deleteCheckedBoxes();
  } 
 function sendPositiveRecognitionEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent')
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getLastRow()
  var studentFirstNameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
  var studentFirstname = studentFirstNameRange.getValues();
  var studentEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("C2:D" + lastRow);
  var studentEmail = studentEmailRange.getValues();
  var parentEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("D2:D" + lastRow);
  var parentEmail = parentEmailRange.getValues();
  var emailSendRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("L2:L" + lastRow);
  var emailSend = emailSendRange.getValues();
  var linkRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("E2:E" + lastRow);
  var link = linkRange.getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i < studentFirstname.length; i++) {
    if (emailSend[i][0]) {
      // Send Alert Email.
      var message = "Hi " + studentFirstname[i][0] + "! <br><br>You have been doing a great job this year, so we made this for you! Keep up the great work! <br><br>"+ link[i][0] +"<br><br><br>The Supernova Teachers"; // Second column
      var subject = 'Positive Recognition'; 
      MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: studentEmail[i][0] + "," + parentEmail[i][0],
    subject: "Positive Recognition",
    htmlBody: message,
      })
    }  
  } 
}
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {;

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent')
 var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getLastRow()
const colLData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Unsent').getRange("L2:L" + lastRow).getValues();
for(let i = colLData.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
  if(colLData[i][0] === true){
    sheet.moveRows(i+2,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sent'))
    sheet.deleteRows(i+2)
  }
}
};```

Here is the spreadsheet: [Sheet][1]


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFlOg6rQeKARtZmMfyNGgMX8Chtz2XXNosFKxRcEryQ/edit?usp=sharing
````

Comment: About `Basically I am trying to write a script that when I trigger it will:`, in your situation, when do you want to run the script? For example, the multiple values are inputted to the cells and you want to use all inputted values in the script, I cannot understand when you want to run the script. I apologize for this.

Comment: I want to manually trigger the script to run, I have it saved as a macro on the sheet. Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to manually trigger the script to run`. Can you provide the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the destinationIndex parameter for moveRows() can only be an integer.  The best way that I know of to 'move' rows between sheets is to copy the data from the row on the unsent page to a row on the sent page, and then delete the old row.

Try this:

```
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sent = ss.getSheetByName('Sent');
      const unsent = ss.getSheetByName('Unsent');

      const lastRow = unsent.getLastRow()
      const colLData = unsent.getRange("L2:L" + lastRow).getValues();
      for (let i = colLData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (colLData[i][0] === true) {
          // Get Row Value
          let rowToMove = unsent.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, unsent.getLastColumn()).getValues();
          // Set Row Value
          let sendToRow = sent.getRange(sent.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, rowToMove[0].length);
          // Send/Delete Row Data
          sendToRow.setValues(rowToMove)
          unsent.deleteRows(i + 2)
        }
      }
    };
```

Let me know if you still have issues, and welcome to coding!